# Resident memory size RES automatically decreased after 10-day aging

Tags: memory, memory-management

My application consists of multiple processes.
Each of the processes has multiple threads.
Heap memory areas are allocated and freed dynamically during the operation.

I had a memory leaking bug in the application and fixed it.
Then, I conducted an aging test during the new year holidays to prove that the bug had been fixed completely.

During the aging test, another monitoring process periodically read /proc/PID/statm of the application processes and it logged the values in a file.

After 13 days, I analyzed the memory log file.

For the first 10 hours or so, the size of resident memory (RES) kept increasing.
This is an expected behavior because glibc library memory allocator doesn't return "freed memory" to the system and it keeps the memory fragments in "arena" for future reuse.

Then, the size of resident memory (RES) hit the ceiling and stayed flat for 10 days.
This means that the memory leaking bug had been fixed. Hooray!
(Before the fix, it didn't hit any ceiling and it kept increasing.)

To my surprise, after 11 days (about 270 hours), the size of resident memory started decreasing with steep angle (steeper than the increasing period), then hit the "floor" and stayed flat till the end of the aging period.
Most of the application processes showed the same behavior (a few of them didn't).
Their resident memory sizes started decreasing after 270 hours.

Can anyone describe the reason of this decreasing?
Any hypotheses are welcome.

You may ask "what's wrong with the decreasing of RES size?".

The decreasing itself is acceptable, but it seems that it triggers slowing down or temporary pause of timing critical processes and threads in my application.
"What I REALLY want to do" is to remove the cause of such slowing down or temporary pause and to keep the processes and their threads running without any delay.

Environment information:

```
OS: Rocky Linux release 8.8 (Green Obsidian)
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9850HE CPU @ 2.70GHz
Language: C++17
gcc version (dnf info gcc):
  Name         : gcc
  Version      : 8.5.0
  Release      : 18.el8
  Architecture : x86_64
  Size         : 59 M
  Source       : gcc-8.5.0-18.el8.src.rpm
glibc version (dnf info glibc):
  Name         : glibc
  Version      : 2.28
  Release      : 225.el8
  Architecture : x86_64
  Size         : 6.4 M
  Source       : glibc-2.28-225.el8.src.rpm
```

---

I have 2 hypotheses:
1.
Other processes (not the application processes) allocated residential memory for them and the total amount across the system reached its limit.
The application processes were not able to keep freed resident memory areas anymore and they started returning their "hoarded memory areas" to the system.
I checked the result of "top" command on the 13th day, but there was no process with hugely grown RES size.

2.
Linux or glibc memory allocator has a kind of "house keeping" mechanism for automatic trimming of memory space.
It works periodically and forces processes to return their freed memory to the system.

---

I also searched for information on the Internet, but what I found are similar to the following, not about my case of "decreasing".

- [RSS(resident set size) didn't decrease after object destroyed in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69369273/rssresident-set-size-didnt-decrease-after-object-destroyed-in-linux)
- [Understanding glibc malloc trimming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38644578/understanding-glibc-malloc-trimming)

I learned the basics of heap memory management through the debugging (so I learned what is "arena"), but I don't know the detail of it.